# Replacing "?" with the mean

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data set that has a column with many question marks "?", not NA. How can I replace that column with the mean of the numbers in that same column?

Comment: df$coln <- as.numeric(df$coln); df$coln[is.na(df$coln)] <- mean(df$coln, na.rm=T)

Comment: can you please explain what T means ? also, I'm not replacing na. I want to replace the ?'s from the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the column into numeric column. ?s will be converted into NAs. Then calculate the mean of the remaining while excluding the NAs (i.e. na.rm=TRUE) and populate NAs positions with that mean

```
df$coln <- as.numeric(df$coln)
df$coln[is.na(df$coln)] <- mean(df$coln, na.rm=TRUE)
```